# kendo mvc window set to be modal but isn't opening as a modal and wont center properly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an issue with my window element.

This is the code I have in the view

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Modal(true)
    .Name("AddDatabaseModal")
    .Title("Add Database")
    .Visible(false)
    .Width(400)
    )
```

I load it on a button click...

```
function addDatabase() {
    alert("addButtonClicked");
    var selected_pk = $('#database_pk').val();    
    $("#AddDatabaseModal").kendoWindow({
        content: {
            url: "Home/AddDatabase"            
        }
    })
    var window = $("#AddDatabaseModal").data("kendoWindow").center().open();   
}
```

The actionresult is run on the controller and the view is populated and the window opens

BUT  its not a modal  I can click on any of the controls behind which I don't want...and the center for some reason does center it left from right..but pushes the window down so that most of it is below the visible window..I have to scroll down to view the window...and its not because the window is that size to begin with...there is no scroll bar on the browser when I click the button..the window pops open and suddenly there is a scroll bar and I have to scroll down to view the window content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are defining a window in HTML and on the same id again you are defining another window in javascript. Thus two instances of window is created. 
In order to achieve your goal either you define the window in HTML and open that in "addDatabase" function. Or define the window itself inside the "addDatabase" function.

Small demonstartion:

Case 1:

```
  <div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Window()
       .Modal(true)
       .Name("AddDatabaseModal")
       .Title("Add Database")
       .Visible(false)
       .Width(400)
       .LoadContentFrom("AddDatabase", "Home")
)
</div>

<script>
function addDatabase() {
     alert("addButtonClicked");
     var selected_pk = $('#database_pk').val();    
     $("#AddDatabaseModal").data("kendoWindow").center().open();  
}
</script>
```

Case 2:

```
<div id="AddDatabaseModal"></div>

<script>
function addDatabase() {
     alert("addButtonClicked");
     var selected_pk = $('#database_pk').val();    
     $("#AddDatabaseModal").kendoWindow({
                    width: "400px",
                    title: "Add Database",
                    content: "../Home/AddDatabase",
                    visible: false,
                    modal: true
                });
     $("#AddDatabaseModal").data("kendoWindow").center().open();  
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps.
For further query leave your comments.

Comment: Glad that I could help you.:)